# How to return a boolean value indicating an element of an array of object is empty using javascript or lodash

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have an array of object as below.

```
[{key:1, value:'value1'},{key:2, value:'value2'},{key:3, value:''}]
```

I want to check by looping entire dynamic array and return a boolean value which indicates any of the value is empty using plain javascript and lodash. If in the array of object all `value` element is not empty it should return `false` and if any of the `value` is empty it should return `true`. Can anyone please help me to solve the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Array.some()` to iterate the array, and for every object check if the value is an empty string. The method will stop and return `true`, as soon as such value is found. If none found, it will return `false`.

```js
const arr = [{key:1, value:'value1'},{key:2, value:'value2'},{key:3, value:''}]

const result = arr.some(o => o.value === '')

console.log(result)
```